# How to subsitute with variable options in perl script

Tags: perl, replace

In perl text substitutions are very simple and powerful.
I want to do a script with variable substitutions, like:

```
if ( $IgnoreCase ) {$opt = "gi"} else {$opt = "g"}

$string =~ s/$source/$replace/$opt;
```

Results in:

> Scalar found where operator expected ...

Is there a posibility to do the option variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're using `/g` in all cases you can,

```
my $opt = $IgnoreCase ? "(?i)" : "";

$string =~ s/$opt$source/$replace/g;
```

More on this subject in [`perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%5ealupimnsx))

> One or more embedded pattern-match modifiers, to be turned on (or turned off if preceded by "-" ) for the remainder of the pattern or the remainder of the enclosing pattern group (if any).
>
> This is particularly useful for dynamically-generated patterns, such as those read in from a configuration file, taken from an argument, or specified in a table somewhere. Consider the case where some patterns want to be case-sensitive and some do not: The case-insensitive ones merely need to include (?i) at the front of the pattern.

Comment: Could you please explain little bit

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer. It woks perfect form me.

Comment: Things like `i` can be supplied at runtime by using brackets to turn them on and off again. You can't do this with `g` though, because it fundamentally alters the behaviour of the regex engine.

Comment: @ssr1012 `(?i)` is embedded pattern-match modifier as explained in perldoc.

Answer (score 6):

To slightly clarify [the excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47568828/7231) from [Сухой27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927):

As you have seen, you can't use a variable in the options section of the `s///` operator (well, you could if you used `eval` but that would be a very bad idea).

However, that's not the only way to get options into a regex match. You can also use the `(?...)` syntax *inside* the regex string. For example, `m/(?i)foo/` is exactly the same as `m/foo/i`. Note that `/g` is a slightly different class of option, so you can't use that option like this.

But because this `(?...)` string is just part of the regex, you can use a variable to embed it within your regex.

```
my $opt = $IgnoreCase ? "(?i)" : "";

$string =~ s/$opt$source/$replace/g;
```

See ["Extended Patterns" in perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for more details.

Comment: Is there a way to this class of options (like /g) variable?

Comment: @Horst: No, because the `/g` option changes the way the regex engine works in fundamental ways - and once the engine has started up, it's too late to change it.

Comment: Another way to handle this would be a tertiary operator or an if-else control structure that doesn't simply provide the appropriate option(s), but goes further and provides the whole regex. Then the /g option could be in one and not the other.